# prooftree from bussproofs package inside "cases" environment

Tags: math-mode, environments, cases, logic

I am using `bussproofs` package to provide some type proofs. According to `bussproofs` manual, it is impossible to use `prooftree` inside math mode. However, I would like to insert `prooftree` in the `cases` environment. If there are any tricks I can do to overcome this?

The minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\begin{document}
    \[\epsilon=
    \begin{cases}
        \AxiomC{$\alpha$}
        \UnaryInfC{$\beta$}
        \DisplayProof
        %\begin{prooftree}
            %\AxiomC{$\alpha$}
            %\AxiomC{$\beta$}
            %\BinaryInfC{$\gamma$}
        %\end{prooftree}
    \end{cases}\]
\end{document}
```

I want the commented section to compile as well.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using [`bussproofs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bussproofs) may simplify logical proofs as a standalone environment, you have to treat it with care when things become more complex. In general, if you're able to box and store the content, you can always use the box inside your more complex structure.

However, an alternative is to avoid the `bussproofs` package altogether, and stick to traditional `array` constructions to match your logic expressions:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{bussproofs,varwidth}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{bussproofs,varwidth}
\newsavebox{\mypt}
\begin{document}
\begin{lrbox}{\mypt}% Store prooftree in \mypt
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\begin{prooftree}
  \AxiomC{$\alpha$}
  \AxiomC{$\beta$}
  \BinaryInfC{$\gamma$}
\end{prooftree}
\end{varwidth}
\end{lrbox}

\[
  \epsilon =
    \begin{cases}
      \AxiomC{$\alpha$}
      \UnaryInfC{$\beta$}
      \DisplayProof & \text{ if $x$} \\
      \usebox{\mypt} & \text{ if $y$}
    \end{cases}
\]

\hrulefill

\[
  \epsilon = \left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}l@{}}
    \dfrac{~\alpha~}{\beta} & \text{ if $x$} \\
    \dfrac{~\alpha \qquad \beta~}{\gamma} & \text{ if $y$}
  \end{array}\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

At this point it's a case of playing around with the spacing, although the output is very similar in structure to that of `bussproofs`.