# How to scale prooftree environment (bussproofs package)

Tags: environments, scaling

I am using package `bussproofs` in order to draw sequent calculus style proofs.
The proofs are often lengthy and would like to scale them but I can not do it.
There is an uninformative error raised:

> ! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a
>   missing \item.

As you can see scaling and `prooftree` environments work separately,
but not together.

Do you have any suggestions how to scale prootrees?
There is no information about it in `bussproofs` guide.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{prooftree}
    \AxiomC{A}
    \AxiomC{B}
    \BinaryInfC{C}
\end{prooftree}

\scalebox{.6}{The problem}

\scalebox{.6}{
    \begin{prooftree}
        \AxiomC{A}
        \AxiomC{B}
        \BinaryInfC{C}
    \end{prooftree}
}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Since it's first Q

Comment: If you're not fully forced to use `bussproofs`, an ordinary `array` environment will also do. See [`prooftree` from `bussproofs` package inside `cases` environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102034/5764). It makes life simpler, if you're willing to manage some of the spacing yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the following example I defined a `scprooftree` environment having as mandatory argument the scale factor to be used; this environment is a simple modification of `prooftree` as implemented in `bussproofs.sty`:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newenvironment{scprooftree}[1]%
  {\gdef\scalefactor{#1}\begin{center}\proofSkipAmount \leavevmode}%
  {\scalebox{\scalefactor}{\DisplayProof}\proofSkipAmount \end{center} }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{prooftree}
  \AxiomC{A}
  \AxiomC{B}
  \BinaryInfC{C}
\end{prooftree}
\scalebox{.6}{No problem anymore}
\begin{scprooftree}{0.6}
  \AxiomC{A}
  \AxiomC{B}
  \BinaryInfC{C}
\end{scprooftree}
\begin{scprooftree}{2}
  \AxiomC{A}
  \AxiomC{B}
  \BinaryInfC{C}
\end{scprooftree}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The original problem is originated because `prooftree` environment uses the `center` environment; the same error will be triggered by trying to do something like

```
\scalebox{0.6}{\begin{center}A\end{center}}
```

The solution scales the object and *then* uses `center` to center it. Another option would have been to use a `\vbox` to box the entire `prooftree` environment and then to scale it.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the prooftree environment in \parbox also solves the problem but the default centering is lost and a user should center it using width value of \parbox and centering environment.

```
\scalebox{.6}{
\parbox{1cm}{
    \begin{prooftree}
        \AxiomC{A}
        \AxiomC{B}
        \BinaryInfC{C}
    \end{prooftree}}
}
```