# How to align something to the paper diagonal

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I drew a very large proof tree using bussproofs. Now, it does not fit on the page in either horizontal or vertical alignment, but it would fit on the page if I could align it to the diagonal of the sheet. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `Rotating` package?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by aligning to the diagonal. Do you want the big proof centered both horizontally and vertically with respect to the physical sheet of paper? Does it have a caption?

Comment: I want the right end of the proof to be in the upper right corner and the left end of the proof to be in the lower left corner.

@Bernard: I used that to rotate my proof tree by 90 deg, but how can I change the angle?

Comment: `\rotatebox{120}{…}`from the `graphicx` package, or `\turnbox}{120} {…}` from `rotating` to have a rotation of 120°. You have to find the exact angle for the diagonal. Maybe better, use node connection labels from `pst-node` (of the `pstricks` family).

Comment: I can't get this to work. Keeps telling me: `Somethings wrong -- perhaps a missing  \item` if I put `\begin{rotate}{-120}` around my `\begin{prooftree}`

Comment: Why don't you just use \resizebox{\textwidth}{\textheight}{...} to force it to fit?

Comment: If you posted a compilable example, somebody would be able to show you precisely how to do it. Instead of that, people can't do much more than give you some hints. If those aren't enough, do what you should always do: include code we can copy-paste-compile to reproduce a minimal example of the problem.

Comment: That said, I cannot say that this sounds like a good idea. Although scaling is not good, it may be the best option in this case. Perhaps better, though, would be to switch down to a standard font size for the diagram e.g. `\small` or `\footnotesize` for that page.

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly the same problem. Firstly wrap the tree in `\vbox{}` and then you should be able to rotate it by wrapping all that in `\rotatebox{-60}{}`. The -60 seemed to be the right angle for me to align the tree from the top left corner to bottom right corner. Though I also had to wrap it all in `\scalebox{0.8}{}` to fit in on the page!

Link below describes why all this works (I'm not too sure myself).

[How to scale prooftree environment (bussproofs package)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104554/how-to-scale-prooftree-environment-bussproofs-package)

Comment: I've added in some more detail on how to solve the problem, but I don't understand why it works enough to explain it here too. Like I say I'm a total beginner, but I just wanted to share the answer after spending a few hours finding it, to save someone else the same hassle in the future.