# Scale Proof Tree with ebproof

Tags: fontsize, scaling, width, logic

Im using ebproof for proof trees and want to know if there is some way to scale the size of the trees.

Something like [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104554/how-to-scale-prooftree-environment-bussproofs-package), but for ebproof package.

If that is not possible, maybe some way to change font size would be useful to make the tree more compact.

Comment: Welcome to Please give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. Cutting your code down to a MWE may well reveal what your problem actually is. In any case, it is really difficult to help you without more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not completely sure which kind of scaling you have in mind, but `\scalebox` from the `graphicx` package does scale proofs in some way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ebproof}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\someproof
  {\begin{prooftree}
   \Hypo{ \Gamma &\vdash A \to B }
   \Infer[no rule]1{ \Gamma &\vdash {!A} \multimap B }
   \Hypo{ \Delta &\vdash A }
   \Infer[rule thickness=2pt]1{ \Delta &\vdash {!A} }
   \Infer0{ B \vdash B }
   \Infer[dashed]2{ \Delta, {!A}\multimap B \vdash B }
   \Infer2{ \Gamma, \Delta &\vdash B }
   \Infer[double]1{ \Gamma \cup \Delta &\vdash B }
   \end{prooftree}%
  }

\scalebox{0.5}{\someproof}

\scalebox{0.4}{\someproof}

\scalebox{0.3}{\someproof}

\scalebox{0.2}{\someproof}
\end{document}
```

[image]